# How to set delay time when search in android

Tags: android

I'm about to search, I want when typing the first keyword will then request the second keyword to delay 2 seconds to request, if less than 2 seconds then no request,Can you help me idea? thanks

Comment: if I understand, you want to make a searcher that can search the first keyword and after the second input search you need to wait at least 2 seconds, I'm right?

Answer (score 0):

An interesting question, maybe several ways to solve it, here is my answer:

```
        editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);

        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (charSequence.subSequence(start, start + 1).toString().equals(" ")) {
                    editText.setEnabled(false);
                    editText.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            editText.setEnabled(true);
                        }
                    }, 2000);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
```

in above codes, I suppose **blank character** is the divider of two keywords, and codes are self explanatory, so comments are omitted, hope helpful!